# How to change design of my dropdown list in css

Tags: css, yii

Is it possible to change design of my combo box in CSS?

I've changed design of combo but when I click on it in dropdown list there are ugly scrollbar, can I change him somehow? I don't use JavaScript, only CSS.

This is my CSS and HTML:

```
.dropDownList {
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: url(arrow1.png) no-repeat right #fff;
    border-style: outset;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

<select onchange="document.location.href = &quot;/pepa/index.php?r=WppActs/create&amp;idp=1830&amp;ida=1&amp;idg=11&amp;idpod=-1&amp;result=arhiva&amp;idgod=&quot;+this.value+&quot;&amp;idbroja=-1&amp;idar=-1&amp;idgr=-1&amp;idvs=-1&amp;ids=-1&amp;idpo=-1&amp;idpm=-1&amp;idakta=-1&quot;" class="dropDownList" name="ID" id="ID">
    <option value="">Година</option>
    <option value="97">1945</option>
    <option value="163">1946</option>
    <option value="224">1947</option>
    <option value="283">1948</option>
    <option value="339">1949</option>
    <option value="375">1950</option>
    <option value="414">1951</option>
    <option value="452">1952</option>
    <option value="499">1953</option>
    <option value="565">1954</option>
    <option value="9974">1955</option>
    <!-- lots more options -->
</select>
```

The PHP used to generate the list is:

```
<?php
    $m = OgNumbers::model()->getYear();
    $list = CHtml::listData($m, 'ID', 'og_year');
    $select = $idGodine;

    echo CHtml::dropDownList('ID', $select, $list, array('empty' => 'Година','onchange' => 'document.location.href = "/pepa/index.php?r=WppActs/create&idp='.$idPaketa.'&ida='.$idOblast.'&idg='.$idG‌​rupa.'&idpod='.$idPodgrupe.'&result='.$result.'&idgod="+this.value+"&idbroja='.$i‌​dBroja.'&idar='.$idaRegistra.'&idgr='.$idgRegistra.'&idvs='.$idVrstaSuda.'&ids='.‌​$idSuda'"','class'=>'dropDownList','size'=>5));
<?php>
```

Comment: make a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: I dont have javascript or html. I have that combo that communicate with db in php and in css i want to change color of scrollbar cause i change some things. I dont know how to do that what you said :( cause i dont have javascript or html just css

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax [DropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DropDown/DropDown.aspx) or [ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) control. It supports css that you can modify

Comment: Thank you on reply but i would like to that over css cause that is my application...

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are targetting Webkit browsers, there are some pseudo classes that can be used to customise the scrollbars - see http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ for a good example.

The pseudo classes are:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-resizer
```

A very simple styling could be something like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umjmW/) using the following pseudo classes:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:lightblue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**Edit:** An updated [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umjmW/1/) using `<ul>` as a container (code now removed from answer since it turns out the container is `<select>` - see edited question).

Comment: yes I done that but he doesn't change at all...Here is the code that I done:.dropDownList::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.dropDownList::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropDownList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

Comment: When I write just webkit-scrollbar and then I changed scrollbar on my browser, but I want change color of my combo scrollbar not of my browser :( and this is really frustrating, is this possible?

Comment: Thank you on help with this, and great this but I would like to apply that when I open my combo change my scrollbar...Cause when I click on that I get list with that ugly scrollbar :(

Comment: The difference with my demo is that I added a `size="5"` to the `<select>`. A size >= 2 will be needed to show the styled scrollbars.

Comment: I dont understand :( what i suppose to do? where to put that size? i dont have <select>...please help...

Comment: I'm guessing `.dropDownList` is not applied to a `<select>` element? Are you using `<div class="dropDownList>` or a `<ul>`? Can you edit your question and add the HTML you are using please?

Comment: that was php and i have css  class  .dropdownList {} that I put

Comment: And I wrote now this size 5 in php I get it inside combo not in list

Comment: That is the code to generate your list. We need to see the HTML that this PHP generates. You need to _Right click_ -> _View page source_ in the browser and add the HTML for the list. Please add this to your **question** above and not as a comment on my answer.

Comment: Is this ok? I put that above?

Comment: Thank you really cause you helping me :)

Comment: I _think_ you are using `yii` framework and from the PHP it looks like the `size` is correct however, in the generated HTML, the _size_ attribute is missing, so the CSS will not be applied. `size="5"` needs to be an attribute of the `<select>`

Comment: Yes, I'm using yii and php. I put like you said size=5 and he cahnged inside of combo and now I have different scrollbar, but I couldn't cange on click - only inside himself, not when I click on list...Is there solution for that or to change so to make like this- list box with scrollbar?

Comment: I _think_ I understand. The PHP is generating a a `<select>` with an *onchange* event but when we added a `size` the `<select>` will be rendered as a _scrollbox_. The *onchange* event will will work if you click on an option. If you are having a problem with the JavaScript event I think that should be asked as a different question, as I think this question on adding custom CSS scrollbars has now been answered, since you have confirmed that the scrollbar is different.